# Always connection refused using telnet

Tags: smtp, centos, telnet

I'm having trouble using telnet locally.

I issued this command and got these results:

```
[root@myserver ~]# telnet localhost 25
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

Here is my iptables result:

```
[root@myserver ~]# iptables --line-numbers -n -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:25 
2    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:465 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

Is there anything else i should do?

Comment: Is your telnet server restricted to listening to a specific IP? Then try that one instead of localhost.

Comment: Are you running an SMTP server on localhost? That's what normally listens on port 25.

Answer (score 0):

Default telnet port is 23. Did you actually open 25 port instead? And I suggest check your settings step by step. Try without iptables and make sure if your telnet working properly. then apply iptables rules.

Comment: How do i check my settings? and how to i unapply the iptables rules?

Comment: Normally you can stop iptables like this.
`# /etc/init.d/iptables stop`
but depends on distribution.

also check your SELinux.
`# getenforce`
If you get result "Enforcing" then
`# setenforce 0`
to temporary disabled.

by the way, you want to talk to your SMTP server via telnet? If it's so, forget about port 23 as I mentioned before.